I want the magnetic torque on a paramagnetic sample. I found the equation I want but I wish to derive it from fundamentals for better understanding

Above equation gives the magnetic torque on a paramagnetic sample

Since when is torque measured in kilonewtons? This source seems confused about force vs. torque.

@Ghoster is correct, the units of torque will be $M\cdot B$ and not $M\cdot B / distance$ (that's force)

We strongly discourage posting images of text and mathematics.  Please use the formatted text options provides together with Mathjax, which is the site standard.  Note that images of text and mathematics cannot be searched or indexed in any way by the system or search engines.
